# Evaluating expected improvement in Mathematica

Tags: probability-or-statistics, integral-equations

There is a concept in optimization called expected improvement where you sequentially search for the value of x that optimizes the problem. Here is a screen shot of the general idea of the derivation:

[image]

Now, what I am trying to figure out is how to evaluate the expected value of the improvement function in Mathematica?

Here is code that I have tried, but for some reason it is not returning the answer I would have expected. Can anyone please point out why what I am doing is wrong, or give Mathematica code that does the correct evaluation?

Here is my code:

```
Expectation[Max[f-Y,0], Y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[mu,sigma]]
```

which returns the following incorrect expression:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [...] which returns the following incorrect expression:

[image: OPimg]

***No, the expression computed by Mathematica is correct.***

Below that is verified.

#### 1

> "where ,  are the PDF and CDF of standard normal distribution, respectively."

Definitions as in OP's question:

```
\[Phi][x_] := Evaluate[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x]];
\[CapitalPhi][x_] := Evaluate[CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x]];
```

#### 2

Code from OP's question:

```
res1 = Expectation[
  Max[f - (\[Mu] + \[Sigma] \[Epsilon]), 0], \[Epsilon] \[Distributed] 
   NormalDistribution[0, 1], Assumptions -> \[Sigma] > 0]

(* (E^(-((f - \[Mu])^2/(
  2 \[Sigma]^2))) (E^((f - \[Mu])^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2)) f Sqrt[\[Pi]] - 
   E^((f - \[Mu])^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2)) Sqrt[\[Pi]] \[Mu] + Sqrt[2] \[Sigma] + 
   E^((f - \[Mu])^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2)) f Sqrt[\[Pi]]
     Erf[(f - \[Mu])/(Sqrt[2] \[Sigma])] - 
   E^((f - \[Mu])^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2))
     Sqrt[\[Pi]] \[Mu] Erf[(f - \[Mu])/(Sqrt[2] \[Sigma])]))/(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]]) *)
```

#### 3

Simplified result:

```
res1 = FullSimplify[res1]

(* (E^(-((f - \[Mu])^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2))) \[Sigma])/Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] + 
 1/2 (f - \[Mu]) (1 + Erf[(f - \[Mu])/(Sqrt[2] \[Sigma])]) *)
```

#### 4

The right hand side of the last EI(x) formula in OP's  question:

```
res2 = (f - \[Mu])*\[CapitalPhi][(f - \[Mu])/\[Sigma]] + \[Sigma]*\[Phi][(
    f - \[Mu])/\[Sigma]]

(* (E^(-((f - \[Mu])^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2))) \[Sigma])/Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] + 
 1/2 (f - \[Mu]) Erfc[-((f - \[Mu])/(Sqrt[2] \[Sigma]))] *)
```

#### 5

Compare the results:

```
FullSimplify[res1 == res2]

(* True *)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Anton for that thorough explanation! If I wanted to compute the expectation of the squared improvement function, would it just `Expectation[Max[f-Y,0]^2, Y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[mu,sigma]]` and then I can use the `FullSimplify` command to reduce it?

Comment: @JohnSmith Sure, it is seems to work.

Comment: Maybe a naive question, but is it possible for you to point out which pieces of the solution in res1 are equal to the pieces in res 2? I believe they are equal based on your code, but I am not sure which part is the CDF and which part is the PDF, i.e., how they collapse to the final answer.

Comment: I figured it out, nevermind.